# How do I upload Icons from material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I have run npm install using material-ui icons

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

and imported the search icon in my code but I have not getting any output.

```
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
```

when I call the search icon

```
<SearchIcon />
```

the program outputs a blank screen but without it the code works fine. Does anyone know why the icon is not showing?

This is my code if it helps
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icons are not exported as default on the Material UI library. Therefore you also shouldn't try to import them as default. Try something like this:

`import { Search as SearchIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";`