# Facing error while using materisl-ui icons in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have used the commands `npm install @material-ui/core` and `npm install @material-ui/icons` in my react app and want to use the FileUploadIcon. I am importing it by using

```
import { FileUploadIcon } from '@material-ui/icons/FileUpload';
```

and later

```
<input type= "file" id = "file" onChange={checkJSON}/>
<label for = "file">
<FileUploadIcon />
    Choose a JSON file
</label>'
```

I am getting the error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/FileUpload' in 'F:\Profile\Desktop\New\UI\react-jwt-auth-master\src\components'
```

My package.json has these dependencies

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
```

Comment: material-ui version 1-4 are available on NPM under @material/core and versions >4 are available under @mui/material. Same library, but they changed the name in version 5

Answer (score 0):

icon import code needs to be changed

change this code

```
import { FileUploadIcon } from '@material-ui/icons/FileUpload';
```

like this

```
import { FileUploadIcon } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

a solution to this question will help us

[How do I upload Icons from material-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70629595/how-do-i-upload-icons-from-material-ui)

Comment: Still getting the same error Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in 'F:\Profile\Desktop\New\UI\react-jwt-auth-master\src\components'

Comment: without installing a new package 

I think we need to change the import code like this 

import { FileUploadIcon } from '@material-ui/icons';

Comment: Attempted import error: 'FileUploadIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/icons'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search here to see which icons are part of @material-ui/icons: https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/. FileUploadIcon is not there.

If you have the svg for an icon such as from the material.io site, you can create an SvgIcon element by grabbing the path element from the svg:

Please refer this link: [Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ContentCut'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543530/module-not-found-cant-resolve-material-ui-icons-contentcut)